# How to set a default sorting to a jh-table?

Tags: jhipster

I have a jh-table with a working header that sorts by each field, but I would like to have it sorted by a specific field by default when the page is loaded.

I tried to set orderBy in the ng-repeat of the tbody, but I think it is causing a conflict with jh-sort and the sorting buttons stop working properly.

Is there a way to define the default sorting in the thead?

This is my thead:

```html
<thead>
    <tr jh-sort="vm.predicate" ascending="vm.reverse" callback="vm.transition()">
        <th jh-sort-by="id"><span data-translate="global.field.id">ID</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
        <th jh-sort-by="name"><span data-translate="global.field.name">Nome</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
        <th jh-sort-by="date"><span data-translate="cccApp.certificateRequestBatch.creationDate">Data de cadastro</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
        <th jh-sort-by="status"><span data-translate="global.field.status">Situo</span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort"></span></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `certificateRequestBatch` entity state file (`certificate-request-batch.state.js`), you can set the default params for sorting/pagination via the `sort` key:

```
params: {
    page: {
        value: '1',
        squash: true
    },
    sort: {
        value: 'id,asc',
        squash: true
    },
    search: null
},
```

A full example of the entity state for AngularJS [can be seen here](https://github.com/ruddell/jhipster-examples/blob/3cc86915fde7c4e87d3ca54ee9dcdbe0b7b66efc/src/main/webapp/app/entities/certificate-request-batch/certificate-request-batch.state.js#L26-L36).